# Parsley js breaks the glyphicon alignment on validation error

Tags: html, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, parsley.js

I have a password input box which contains a glyphicon info image on the right side. I am using parsley.js to validate this input box. On form submit if password validation fails parsley displays the error message beneath the input box as expected but also breaks the alignment of the glyphicon icon and makes it protrude out of the input box. Please find jsfiddle demo here
 https://jsfiddle.net/bsbef0qd/2/ . Thanks

```
<form id="form" data-parsley-validate="">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="input-group add-on">
      <input type="password" name="userFormPassword" id="userFormPassword" value="" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Some password instructions"> 
        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label for="confirm" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirm" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the error displaying position..

Add this part to your form tag as a attribute "`data-parsley-errors-container="#errorContainer"`"

```
<form id="form" data-parsley-validate="" data-parsley-errors-container="#errorContainer">
```

put this div to where you want the errors to display

```
<div id="errorContainer"></div>
```

I have edited your fiddle check the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bsbef0qd/5/)

Also Check the Plugin documentation [**here**](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html)

Comment: I purposely copy this URL from my incognito mode to here just to give you +1

Answer (score 1):

also, you can use `data-parsley-errors-container="#your-div-id"` in your input element

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Start Time</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class=" datetimepicker3 input-append timepick">
          <input class="form-control" data-format="hh:mm" placeholder="HH:MM" type="text" name="startTime" data-parsley-errors-container="#startTimeErrorContainer" required="required"  id="startTime" />
          <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-clock-o icon-time"></i></span>  
       </div>   
      <div id="startTimeErrorContainer"></div>                                            
  </div>
```